# How to remove div without inner elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to remove one div element, but without its children. For example, let's say that i have one div with id wrapper, and inside it 5 paragraphs.

I want to remove only the wrapper div, but to leave paragraphs alive. I have tried both remove() and detach(), but they both clean out the inner elements.

Any advice?

Comment: Older question, probably with obsolete answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032317/how-can-i-remove-a-surrounding-div-with-jquery

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/ should do it:

> The `.unwrap()` method removes the element's parent. This is effectively the inverse of the [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method. The matched elements (and their siblings, if any) replace their parents within the DOM structure...

Answer (score 6):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/d9PQY/)

```
$('#element').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: Might be @Robert, but doing just `.unwrap()` you'll do nothing (if you use the 'parent' as a selector).

Answer (score 4):

Check out [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
$('#theDiv').replaceWith($('#theDiv').contents());
```

Comment: You are the saviour. I'm using one CMS, which tends to add wrapper div to any content added through HTML editor. But it messed up my absolute positioned elements, so i needed to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourdivIDtoremove').replaceWith($(this).text());
```

should do ;)

Comment: Someone already provided a `replaceWith` answer four minutes ago.

Comment: `text()` will wipe out html tags