# Dropdown converted to radio buttons, no longer triggering specific function

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

I'm building off an existing woocommerce wordpress extension, and I'm converting the product variation (size, color etc) dropdown menus into radio boxes. The trickiness is that when a user selects an option from the drop-down list, it triggers something that automatically updates the product inventory and price via ajax.

I used this to convert the inputs into radios (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029267/jquery-convert-select-to-radio-buttons)):

```
$('.variations select').each(function(i, select){
    var $select = jQuery(select);
    $select.find('option').each(function(j, option){
        var $option = jQuery(option);
        // Create a radio:
        var $radio = jQuery('<input type="radio" />');
        // Set name and value:
        $radio.attr('name', $select.attr('name')).attr('value', $option.val());
        // Set checked if the option was selected
        if ($option.attr('selected')) $radio.attr('checked', 'checked');
        // Insert radio before select box:
        $select.before($radio);
        $radio.wrap('<div class="vari-option fix" />');
        // Insert a label:
        $radio.before(
          $("<label />").attr('for', $select.attr('name')).text($option.text())
        );
    });
```

Then I've used this

```
$(':radio').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().find('label').removeClass('checked');
   $(this).siblings('label').addClass('checked');
   $choice = $(this).attr('value');
   $('.variations select option[value=' + $choice + ']').attr('selected',true);
});
```

So that when a radio is selected, it mirrors the event on the dropdown option. That works fine, but it's not triggering the refresh of the product info. My guess is there's a difference between changing the 'selected' attribute of a dropdown option and physically clicking on the same option. Any guess at what event might be triggering that ajax function that I'm not taking into account? And a solution that ideally doesn't involve modifying woocommerce's original code? I've tried using .click() on the select option but it made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programmatically changing the value of an element doesn't trigger the `change` event, and I would assume that programmatically setting the `selected` attribute/property on an `<option>` also wouldn't trigger the `change` event on the containing `<select>` element.

Fortunately, you can easily trigger that event programmatically using jQuery:

```
$('.variations select option[value=' + $choice + ']').attr('selected',true).parent().trigger('change');
```

The `.parent()` call returns a jQuery object containing the `<select>` element, then `.trigger('change')` triggers any event handlers bound to the `change` event on that object.