# Convert Woocommerce Attribute Dropdown to Clickable Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a WC website and I'd like to change the display of the attributes. Rather than display them as a dropdown form element, each attribute should be displayed as a text link. Here's an example site that does it right with the shoe sizes: http://shop.nordstrom.com/s/vince-addie-sandal/3761939?origin=category

I purchased the Variations Swatches and Images plugin for the site. It works for product sizing (it's easy to predict product sizes, so I could make the images) but the product colors are custom for each item (Berry, Turquoise, etc). The end client isn't saavy enough to generate an image of text for every color possibility, however.

I considered converting the dropdown to radio buttons ([seen here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374110/converting-woo-commerce-dropdowns-into-radio-buttons/24973672#24973672)), removing the radio elements, and styling the labels, but the WP plugin that's available doesn't generate valid labels to click on. Admittedly, my JS knowledge is limited to basic scripts and tinkering, so building a custom thing would be hard...

Any ideas of where to go from here would be appreciated. Here's what I'm considering:

- Modifying the SO post from above to have valid labels and pray it works
- Adding in color swatches for the shoes as colors or text every time
- Leaving the colors as a drop down and asking client to work with it (not good)

Comment: Can you show us your current page example?

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ Sure, would you just like to see what I have on the website or the code?

Comment: Sorry Stevie, I actually realized I don't need to look at your code at the moment. Please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

1. [The example site you provided](http://shop.nordstrom.com/s/vince-addie-sandal/3761939?origin=category) is not a WooCommerce site (it's not even WordPress);
2. There's a plugin which I'm sure you'll find helpful: [Woocommerce Radio Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-radio-buttons/); It turns drop-downs into radio buttons, which you can easily customize with just plain CSS; Here's an example to show how radio buttons can be made to look like regular buttons:

HTML:

```
<ul class="donate-now">
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="a25" name="amount" />
    <label for="a25">$25</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="a50" name="amount" />
    <label for="a50">$50</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="a75" name="amount" checked="checked" />
    <label for="a75">$75</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="a100" name="amount" />
    <label for="a100">$100</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="other" name="amount" />
    <label for="other">other:</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="text" id="otherAmount" name="numAmount" />
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.donate-now {
     list-style-type:none;
     margin:25px 0 0 0;
     padding:0;
}

.donate-now li {
     float:left;
     margin:0 5px 0 0;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    position:relative;
}

.donate-now label, .donate-now input {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.donate-now input[type="radio"] {
    opacity:0.011;
    z-index:100;
}

.donate-now input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:yellow;
}

.donate-now label {
     padding:5px;
     border:1px solid #CCC; 
     cursor:pointer;
    z-index:90;
}

.donate-now label:hover {
     background:#DDD;
}
```

[Here's a demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YB8UW/8/).

Please let me know if you need any further assistance.

### Edit

Okay, so the existing plugin doesn't fit your needs exactly, so I modified it a bit.

1. Uninstall the previously installed WooCommerce Radio Buttons plugin;
2. Download and install the modified plugin [from here](http://www.filedropper.com/woocommerce-improved-radio-buttons_1);
3. Optional: Go to `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-improved-radio-buttons/woocommerce/assets/frontend/css/` and edit the `add-to-cart-variation.css` file to your liking;

If you're interested to see how the code looks like, feel free to look inside.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response! As for 1, I know it's not Woo, but I provided it as a visual example of what I'd like to accomplish. As for the example code, when I tried the WP plugin to convert the selects to radios, the HTML output doesn't use labels. Here's a copy/paste of its output on my site: `<input id="pa_shoe-size" type="radio" name="attribute_pa_shoe-size" value="10">
10
<br>
<input id="pa_shoe-size" type="radio" name="attribute_pa_shoe-size" value="5">
5
<br>`

Comment: I see what you mean. In this case I'm afraid you'll have to modify the plugin's template file as well as a few other plugin files. Hang on for a moment, I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: I see what you did - and I think I can do that modification. I'll have to apply it tonight and see, but I'll let you know how it works.